# Ada programming. What is the difference between Put and Put_line

Tags: ada

I'm trying to learn Ada. What is the difference between Put and Put_line?  I think I see them used interchangeably but can not confirm that.

```
begin
Put("Please type in your name:  ");
get_line(yourName, Length);
New_Line;
Put(yourName(1..Length));
Put(" landed on an alien planet and was attacked by 50 aliens. ");
Put(yourName(1..Length));
Put(" fought bravely and killed 12 attackers, ");
Put("after which the reamining aliens fled.  ");
Put(yourName(1..Length));
Put(" was able to crawl back to his ship" );
Put(" where his medical officer successfully treated his wounds.");
end Short_Story2;
```

Comment: I don't see where/how there's a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

`Put_line` outputs its input and terminates the line, `Put` does not. Hence `Put_Line("This"); Put_Line("That");` produces

```
This
That
```

While `Put("This"); Put("That");` produces

```
ThisThat
```

Comment: That makes sense.  But I want to put a sample of Ada code that kind of contradicts your answer.  But My code does not look neatly readable.  I'll put it in my original question.

Comment: Do that; I'll try to help answer your questions.

Comment: When I run the executable, this output is broken up into lines ( 4 of them)  I would think this would be one long line.  Is the Windows command line window doing that formatting?

Comment: It is one long line; the terminal window handles line overflow by wrapping to the next line. Try with shorter & longer names.

Comment: Simon I will try that.

Comment: Hi Guys. I tried some Put/Put_Line tests and saw the results as Shark8 had stated.  Sorry I doubted you but I did have fun testing.  Thank you for helping Shark8 and Simon Wright.

Comment: For some reason when using Put the last string has a line break, too. So its `ThisThat\n` instead of `ThisThat`

Comment: @MarcelHernandez - If it's the last output [to standard output] of the program, IIRC, the runtime fixes things up with a new-line so you don't get the prompt smashed into the output: `Some-outputC:\>` (or whatever your prompt is).